# Asset Catalog Compile Error

Tags: ios, xcode

I think ive done a bad manipulation and my project dont run since, ive tried every solutions on stackoverflow without any good result.

so im desesperate and i prefer to ask.

heres my error message : /Users/dev/Documents/Work/TheSecondLast/TheSecondLast/Assets.xcassets: None of the input catalogs contained a matching launch image set named  "LaunchImage".

[Here is my screenshot]-->[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpGZM.png)

I Really hope someone will have the time to help me and i thank you all even if you dont.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the target, switch to the General pane, and fix these setting to look this:

[image]

The problem is that you pressed the Use Asset Catalog button, which means your asset catalog contains a launch image — but it doesn't. If you configure as shown below, you'll go back to using the LaunchScreen storyboard as your launch image.

Answer (score 1):

Met same issue, solved it by removing build settings' `ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_LAUNCHIMAGE_NAME` value "LaunchImage":

[image]