# LaunchImages missing from iOS xamarin project

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

when running my application on android it works and behaves fine. But when running my application on iOS, i'm presented with the error `None of the input catalogs contained a matching launch image set named "LaunchImages".`

So what I've done is I've examined my Images.xcassets and I can indeed see LaunchImages filder was not present. So I've copied it over from my other project temporarily but that unfortunately didn't resolve the issue.

Any tips or suggestion would be greatly appreciated

Comment: 1) Is this a new Xamarin forms solution? 2) Are you using Windows or Mac? 3) In your info.plist file, what do you see under source: & screen: ?

Comment: Hi, you should set the recommended name(LaunchImagexx) in `Asset Catalogs`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asset Catalog Compile Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47502376/asset-catalog-compile-error)